# Single spa integration issue with material ui styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, single-page-application, single-spa

We are trying to integrate Single spa with React and Material UI.
We have 2 React applications with Material UI:

1. The root container.
2. A microfront (spa application).

When we integrate both components we have the following error:

**It looks like there are several instances of `@material-ui/styles` initialized in this application. This may cause theme propagation issues, broken class names, specificity issues, and makes your application bigger without a good reason. See https://material-ui.com/r/styles-instance-warning for more info.**

The configuration files are like this:

**webpack.config.**  With this configuration we want to externalize so that it uses the material ui dependency present in the root container application.

[image: webpack.config.js]

**index.js**. We are registering the microfront.

[image: index.js]

**index.html** We are using the systemjs to load the material modules and the microfront.

[image]

We followed the steps suggested in this page without getting any satisfactory result:

https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#i-have-several-instances-of-styles-on-the-page

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I've also been struggling with material UI in Single Spa micro-frontends, since I also had multiple dependencies for material-ui, which caused random rendering errors.

In order to prevent that, you need to use material-ui as in-browser module, so you only have one copy that your micro-frontends will use. For this, it needs to be compatible with SystemJS. More info: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#systemjs

In order to do so, the easiest way is using UMD script. For example, if you are using @material-ui/core version 4.11.3, you will need this script:

"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@material-ui/core@4.11.3/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"

You will have to load that script with the rest of your import maps:

for example:

```
    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js",
          "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
          "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.8.2/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
          "rxjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/rxjs@6.6.6/system/es2015/rxjs.min.js",
          "@material-ui/core": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@material-ui/core@4.11.3/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Another possibility is using JSPM to load your dependencies as import maps. You can find an example here: https://github.com/jspm/project/issues/99

Finally, you can always pack your dependency in one of your shared components and share it from there. Since your shared components are in-browser modules, you will have only one copy.

I hope that was useful

Answer (score 3):

I have the same setup as the above comment, but it did not fully solve the issue for me for multiple microfrontends. What did solve it for me was this:

I believe that each microfrontend is injecting its own stylesheet into the DOM, whether that's through calling makeStyles or not, I'm not entirely sure. You can see this in this example - https://d4e2yqa5hvu3s.cloudfront.net/ by inspecting the source and looking at the head tag - there are two MuiTypographys. The source code for that was linked in [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/micro-frontends-ui-jay-saraiya?trk=public_profile_article_view). What I did was I made sure that the import of the material ui components/styles were all consistent. So if you declare in your import map:

```
{
 "@material-ui/core": "<location of js>"
}
```

Then all imports of your components must follow:

`import { x } from '@material-ui/core';`

I also prefaced each style class with a unique name and seed per microfrontend (see above article and [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15914#issuecomment-804931366)). Like:

```
import { ThemeProvider, StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  disableGlobal: true,
  productionPrefix: 'foo', // defaults to 'jss'
  seed: 'bar', // defaults to ''
});
  ...
  <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
  ...
```

I believe I have mitigated any issues (broken styling/propagation), and the warning about multiple styling on the page has now disappeared but if anyone has any more ideas, I'd be interested to hear them :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also necessary to put the material-ui as in webpack externals.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).